# add a space char in Typoscript

Tags: content-management-system, whitespace, typo3, typoscript

I would like to add a blank/whitespace in TypoScript
It concerne a "More"-link in tt_news.

Here's the HTML I have :

```
<p class="bodytext">blablabla<span class="news-list-morelink">&nbsp;<a title="Read all the news" target="_top" href="http://www.google.com">More</a></span></p>
```

And here's what I want :

```
<p class="bodytext">blablabla <span class="news-list-morelink">&nbsp;<a title="Read all the news" target="_top" href="http://www.google.com">More</a></span></p>
```

(the difference is the whitespace juste before the `<span>`.

In my opinion, I must make a change in the TypoScript which generates the link "more".
That must be where I wrote "HERE"

```
plugin.tt_news {
 displayLatest{
  subheader_stdWrap {
   #More link after the bodytext
   append = TEXT
   append.data = register:newsMoreLink
   append.wrap = HERE<span class="news-list-morelink">&nbsp;|</span>
  }
 }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea ?
Thanks...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use noTrimWrap instead of wrap:

```
append.noTrimWrap = | <span class="news-list-morelink">&nbsp;|</span>|
```

See [TSref notrimwrap](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#notrimwrap)

Comment: …I would never have searched for "noTrimWrap"

Comment: Do take a stroll around TSRef, in this case the function stdWrap: http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Stdwrap/Index.html - there are lots of useful functions. As for noTrimWrap, there is, since 6.1, also the possibility to change the pipe for another splitting character.

Comment: Documentation page was moved: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add:

```
NO.afterWrap = &#32
```

Comment: Please in answer only pass the answer, if you also have question pass it as question (keep'em distinct)

Answer (score 0):

I found this technic but I m note quite happy with it

```
append.wrap = <span></span> <span class="news-list-morelink">&nbsp;|</span>
```

HTML gurus'll kill me

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
append.wrap = &nbsp;<span class="news-list-morelink">&nbsp;|</span>
```

?

nbsp will just add a space and no additional span is needed.